# How to share array of objects in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a function in which I create a `pool` of processes. More over I use `multiprocessing.Value()` and `multiprocessing.Lock()` in order to manage some shared values between processes.

I want to do the same thing with an array of objects in order to share it between processes but I don't know how to do it. I will only read from that array.

This is the function:

```
from multiprocessing import Value,Pool,Lock,cpu_count

def predict(matches_path, unknown_path, files_path, imtodetect_path, num_query_photos, use_top3, uid, workbook, excel_file_path,modelspath,email_address):
 
    shared_correct_matched_imgs = Value('i', 0)
    shared_unknown_matched_imgs = Value('i', 0)
    shared_tot_imgs = Value('i', 0)
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    shared_lock = Lock()
    num_workers = cpu_count()
    
    feature = load_feature(modelspath)
    
    pool = Pool(initializer=init_globals,
                initargs=[counter, shared_tot_imgs, shared_correct_matched_imgs, shared_unknown_matched_imgs,
                          shared_lock], processes=num_workers)
    
    for img in glob.glob(os.path.join(imtodetect_path, '*g')):
        pool.apply_async(predict_single_img, (img,imtodetect_path,excel_file_path,files_path,use_top3,uid,matches_path,unknown_path,num_query_photos,index,modelspath))
        index+=increment
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The array is created with the instruction `feature = load_feature(modelspath)`. This is the array that I want to share.

In `init_globals` I inizialize the shared value:

```
def init_globals(counter, shared_tot_imgs, shared_correct_matched_imgs, shared_unknown_matched_imgs, shared_lock):
    global cnt, tot_imgs, correct_matched_imgs, unknown_matched_imgs, lock
    cnt = counter
    tot_imgs = shared_tot_imgs
    correct_matched_imgs = shared_correct_matched_imgs
    unknown_matched_imgs = shared_unknown_matched_imgs
    lock = shared_lock
```

Comment: Did you try `multiprocessing.Array`?

Comment: If you are on a mac or linux machine, you can set the start method to "fork" and create the data at the module level, and it will be copied across to the children automatically due  to the copy-on-write memory used by fork. This only really works for read-only data because any changes don't get reflected in other children or the parent process.

Comment: You may not be modifying the array, but what about the objects within the array. What type of objects are they? Are they able to be pickled? Will their state be modified and so they must be shared?

Comment: Can you use Pool.map? Example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @MarkTolonen I read the documentation of `multiprocessing.Array` but I did not find anything about array of objects.

Comment: @Booboo the array `features` contains informations about a database of images processed. It contains 3 parallel arrays: the first array contains names of images, the second array contains `KeyPoints` of images, the third array contains the `descriptors ` of the KeyPoints. I need to share it between processes because every process take one image in input and comprare it with the "database" of images. This is the reason why it is an only-read array. The problem is that the array of `KeyPoints` is not able to be pickled, so I can not pass it to `pool.apply_async()`. That is why I want to share it

Comment: @Aaron Ok but then should I pass the array as parameter to `pool.apply_async()` ? Will It work if the array contains object that are not able to be pickled?

Comment: @pikuio625 you don't pass it. you just define it in the global scope before forking the child processes, and then use it like any normal global variable. If you do this using "spawn" as the start method, it will create a new copy if that definition is outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, but if you're using fork, It will reference the existing one (google copy on write memory) as long as it remains unmodified.

Comment: You could use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to create shared python objects like lists, but the objects must be picklable.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of providing shared static data is simply to make it a global variable accessible to the function you want to call. If you're using an operating system which supports "fork", it is very straightforward to use global variables in child processes as long as they're constant (if you modify them, changes won't be reflected in the other processes)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from random import randint

shared = ['some', 'shared', 'data', f'{randint(0,1e6)}']

def foo():
    print(' '.join(shared))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    #defining "shared" here would be valid also
    p = mp.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    print(' '.join(shared)) #same random number means "shared" is same object
```

This won't work when using "spawn" as the start method (the only one available on windows), because the memory of the parent is not shared in any way with the child, so the child must "import" the main file to gain access to whatever the target function is (this is also why you can run into problems with decorators.) If you define your data outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, it will kinda work, but you will have made separate copies of the data, which can be undesirable if it's big, slow to create, or can change each time it's created.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from random import randint

shared = ['some', 'shared', 'data', f'{randint(0,1e6)}']

def foo():
    print(' '.join(shared))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("spawn")

    p = mp.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    print(' '.join(shared)) #different number means different copy of "shared" (1 a million chance of being same i guess...)
```

Comment: But  even with `mp.set_start_method("spawn")`, if you needed all processes to see the same data even when you had random generated data like you have, you would be smart enough to call at the global scope `random.seed(1)`, for example, just before you define `shared` and then the main process and the sub-process would print identical results. It's possible to find cases where it will not work for `spawn`, but it may not be relevant to the OP's situation. You just need initialization that is repeatable.

Comment: I think your answer is also implying that with `fork`, unlike with `spawn`, memory is being shared between the main process and a sub-process, but that is not true. If it were, you would never have to pickle and unpickle arguments passed to to your sub-process. It's just that the main process's address space is copied to the new address space as it existed at the point of forking rather than starting off with an "empty" address space that get initialized by re-executing the global code. I think the problem is in the use of your phrase "shared with the child". It should be "copied to child".

Comment: @Booboo Yes, if the initialization is fully repeatable, spawn would still be acceptable. Random was just a quick example to demonstrate that the object was indeed re-created rather than copied. I somewhat disagree with your assessment about fork because until one of the processes modifies the given chunk of memory, it actually does point to the same physical place in memory for both processes. I think in that case "shared" is an appropriate enough word.

Comment: So you are saying that fork is “copy on write”. Interesting.

Comment: @Booboo does it not? [Under Linux, fork() is implemented using copy-on-write pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: I wasn’t disagreeing. I did not know that and honestly found it interesting.

Comment: That's why fork on linux is so worth it  even despite the headaches it comes with in regard to threads. It costs very little cpu or ram to fork a new process. In comparison "spawn" is like a ton of bricks.