# Python multiprocessing with shared RawArray

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to have multiple processes read from a different row of a numpy array in parallel to speed things up. However, when I run the following code, the first process to reach func throws an error as if var is no longer in scope. Why is this happening?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

num_procs = 16
num_points = 2500000

def init_worker(X):
    global var
    var = X

def func(proc):
    X_np = np.frombuffer(var).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    for y in range(num_points):
        z = X_np[proc][y]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.random.randn(num_procs, num_points)
    X = mp.RawArray('d', num_procs*num_points)
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    np.copyto(X_np, data)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4, initializer=init_worker, initargs=(X,))
    for proc in range(num_procs):
        pool.apply_async(func(proc))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    pool.apply_async(func(proc))
  File "parallel_test.py", line 13, in func
    X_np = np.frombuffer(var).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```

Update:
For some reason, if I use Pool.map instead of the for loop with Pool.apply_async, it seems to work. I don’t understand why though.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please add the entire stacktrace to your question, it will help us provide better answers.

Comment: see my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66936542/3220135) on using globals for constants (data you don't change) in multiprocessing. If you want to read data back from the child processes using a real shared array, see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380200/3220135) on the topic from a little while ago.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to use a real shared array, that previous answer was helpful. I’m still not sure what was wrong with what I had though.

Comment: `pool.apply_async(func(proc))` should be `pool.apply_async(func, args=(proc,))`. You were calling `func` from the main process.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to not declare `X` as `global` in the top-level scope? This eliminates the `NameError`.

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

num_procs = 16 
num_points = 25000000


def func(proc):
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    for y in range(num_points):
        z = X_np[proc][y]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.random.randn(num_procs, num_points)
    global X 
    X = mp.RawArray('d', num_procs*num_points)
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    np.copyto(X_np, data)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4 )
    for proc in range(num_procs):
        pool.apply_async(func(proc))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I run a reduced instance of this problem, n=20:

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

num_procs = 4 
num_points = 5


def func(proc):
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    for y in range(num_points):
        z = X_np[proc][y]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.random.randn(num_procs, num_points)
    global X 
    X = mp.RawArray('d', num_procs*num_points)
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X).reshape((num_procs, num_points))
    np.copyto(X_np, data)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4 )
    for proc in range(num_procs):
        pool.apply_async(func(proc))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("\n".join(map(str, X)))
```

I get the following output:

```
-0.6346037804619162
1.1005724710066107
0.33458763357165255
0.6409345714971889
0.7124888766851982
0.36760459213332963
0.23593304931386933
-0.8668969562941349
-0.8842756219923469
0.005979036105620422
1.386422154089567
-0.8770988782214508
0.25187448339771057
-0.2473967968471952
-0.4909708883978521
0.5423521489750244
0.018749603867333802
0.035304792504378055
1.3263872668956616
1.0199839603892742
```

You haven't provided a sample of the expected output. Does this look similar to what you expect?

Comment: Try `get`ting any of the `AsyncResult`s you generate here... you get a name error still because X is not defined in the child processes when spawn is used... (I'm assuming you had a couple commas in your `apply_async` line here too that are just missing in your post. otherwise you're not actually executing anything in the children)

Comment: I was trying to compare how long it takes to iterate through a large array with multiple cores in parallel vs. without, which is why func doesn’t do anything or produce any output.